# simple question on the number of degree in a subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

I have two simple questions. I would like to confirm:

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph.
Let $A$ and $B$ be two subset of vertices.
Let $d_G(A)$ be the sum of degrees of vertices of $A$ : $deg_A=\sum_{v\in V(A)}d_G(v)$

If $A$ and $B$ have no common vertices, can we say:

$d_G(A\cup B)>d_G(A)+d_G( B)$

now, if $A$ and $B$ have common vertices, can we say:

$d_G(A\cup B)> d_G(A)+d_G(B)-d_G(A\cap B)$

Thank you

Comment: Not sure where the inequality comes in, if - as the notation implies - we are just talking about the degree of each vertex in the parent graph $G$

Comment: I think I can understand what your are saying, and I kind of agree. Thank you

In fact, I am trying to understand the inequality from the proof of corollary 2.2.3 of the Diestel"s book, page 44. , 5th edition.

We have a set $S\in G$, $C\in\mathcal{C}_{G-S}$, $C'=C-c$. Then, we have $T=S\cup\{c\}S'$.
Then we have: $d_G(T)\geq d(S)-1-1+d_{C'}(S')$.

I can't figure out where -1 comes from.

Comment: I'm sure folks would be happy to help you understand the proof of a corollary, but it would be helpful to post the original theorem, the corollary, and the proof of the corollary.

Answer (score 1):

> If A and B have no common vertices, can we say: 
>   $d_G(A \cup B)>d_G(A)+d_G(B)$

No. Suppose $G$ contains two connected components, which we call $G_{1}, G_{2}$. Take $A = V(G_{1})$ and $B = V(G_{2})$. Then $\text{vol}(G_{1} \cup G_{2}) = \text{vol}(G_{1}) + \text{vol}(G_{2})$. (Here, $\text{vol}(G_{1}) = \sum_{v \in V(G_{1})} \text{deg}(v)$).

> now, if A and B have common vertices, can we say:  
>   $d_G(A\cup B)>d_G(A)+d_G(B)−d_G(A \cap B)$

Also no. Take $G = K_{1, 4}$. Label the star center as $v_{0}$, and the leaves $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{4}$. Take $A = \{ v_{0}, v_{1}, v_{2}\}$ and $B = \{ v_{0}, v_{3}, v_{4}\}$. So: $\text{vol}(A) = 6, \text{vol}(B) = 6$, and $\text{vol}(A \cap B) = 4$. Furthermore, $\text{vol}(A \cup B) = 8$. So in this case, you get equality, not a strict inequality.

Comment: ml0105: So, in both case, we have large inequalities: $dG(A∪B)\geq dG(A)+dG(B)$ and  $dG(A∪B)\geq dG(A)+dG(B)−dG(A∩B)$

Answer (score 0):

ml0105: Thank you and thank you again.
For the corollary, its a bit long, but here it is:[corrolary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA005.jpg)

[image: sequel]